Two sisters live together and bring home a man
So, there are two sisters who live together in a house, their father died but they have a lot of memories with him and they remember sometimes the words he used to say when they were little girls.
Moving on , the sisters go downtown and they see this guy.They are trying to make him fall in love with them( or something like that, I don't remember very well ) and he is fascinated by one of them and he goes with them...I think he stays there for a while and he falls in love with the blonde one ...at the same time the other sister is quite jealous because she wanted him too and she felt alone.
So, the problem here is that they can't go out of the house, their memories keep them there , especially the memory of their father...
If this rings a bell ...just let me know

Could be Silence Becomes You from 2005 with Alicia Silverstone. From IMDb:

Two sisters, Violet and Grace, very bounded to each other, live in an old mansion with ghosts of their past. Violet meets Luke in a bar, and brings him to her mansion. Along the days, she seduces him, and they have sex many times as part of a plot with Grace. When Luke decides to leave the house with Violet, Grace tries to avoid, and Luke finds that they are trapped in the place.

The sisters live in the shadow of their (probably abusive) father, who appears in many flashback scenes. Here's the trailer [SLIGHTLY NSFW]:



